# How to get the update for a smoke test after releasing a staged rollout on Google PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

We are doing staged rollouts of app updates with a distribution chance of 20% on the google play store. Now usually we do a smoke test after every release on the production track to verify integrity and functionality.

The problem with the staged rollout is, that our QA never knows if they roll the dice in a lucky manner to get the update or not.

**Is there a way to alway get the update for a specific set of people? Or what is the best practice in the `regression test` -> `release` -> `smoke test` procedure?**

#### Update 1

Before we release to the production track, we do a `regression test` on an internal testing track of course.

Comment: You should do beta release and invite a set of users

Comment: Yes, we are doing a regression test before release on an internal testing track (question updated)

Comment: Internal testing track is a way to alway get the update for a specific set of people. Why do you need an extra step here?

Comment: Our smoke test is a final test shortly after release to verify that the product that the user *really* & eventually receives is working fine